# What is the best type of thread-safe queue for multithreaded server in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, queue

I'm writing a server in Java, which - as the title suggests - should be able to handle multiple clients at once. Internally, the server can be divided into one "main" thread which handles internal systems and multiple "worker" threads which are responsible for communicating with specific clients.

The way I'm planning to implement it is to give each thread it's own task queue. Given thread would only be able to remove taks from this queue (dequeue), it would be the responsibility of other threads to add tasks into this queue.
It would look a bit different for main thread than for worker threads - specifically, in case of main thread all other threads would be able to add tasks into it's queue; for worker threads, only main thread could add tasks for them to process (other workers could not, but given the problem I'm solving that shouldn't be necessary anyway).
So, the situation looks like this - for worker threads, one thread will be adding tasks (main thread) and one thread will be removing and executing them (worker); for main thread, multiple threads will be adding tasks (workers), while one will be removing and executing them (main).
It's likely there will be no more ~50-100 clients connected at once.

My question is, what types of queues should I use for storing these tasks for main thread and worker threads? Should I use simple mutex-locked standard library container like `java.util.LinkedList`, thread-safe implementation like `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedDeque`, or maybe something else?

Obviously, main thread and worker threads can use different queue types. All workers should use the same type, though.
I'd also prefer to leave the other decisions outside the scope of this discussion (like using multiple threads instead of executor etc.)

Comment: You've got multiple threads accessing your queues, so you **definitely need thread-safety**.  If it were me I'd just go with either `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` or `ConcurrentLinkedDeque` and never look back.  `LinkedList` is not intrinsically thread-safe, so extra work is necessary to use it in a thread-safe manner.  But why "reinvent the wheel"  when ready-made out-of-the-box thread-safe collection implementations are already available?

Comment: I've heard that for simple setups (which I think the case of worker thread queue is), standard java `LinkedList` locked mutex could be more efficient than concurrent implementations, which is pretty much the only reason I considered them in the first place. Might be just a rumour though. Thanks you for your insights.

Comment: Why not use a built in thread pool? Otherwise `BlockingQueue` would be fairly common so that idle threads are descheduled.

Comment: Thread pools are actually next thing on my to-do list (whis is why I mentioned that I'd rather not discuss it). Right now, communication between tasks seems to be more problematic, though.